# Does chrome.runtime.reload ensures that the Chrome extension gets updated to the current store version?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable listener can take upto few hours to find available updates. If an extension calls chrome.runtime.reload before the call back of the listener, does it get updated to the most recent version (the version in the store)? In other words, does chrome.runtime.reload() ensures that the Chrome extension gets updated to the most recent version even when the browser has not yet notified to have downloaded the newest crx file?

Comment: It won't wait for a new version but it will use the new version if that was already downloaded. So if you call reload() inside onUpdateAvailable listener it should use the new version.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I haven't verified it though...